# query gives two of the same results

Tags: select, join, mysqli

I have the following SQL query but I got a problem:
When I execute it I got two of the same serial numbers from the "sn" column in the "products" table.

```
SELECT specifications.productname, 
products.sn, specifications.year,
lendings.lending_date
FROM products
INNER JOIN lendings ON products.id = lendings.product_id
INNER JOIN specifications ON products.sn LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', specifications.sn, \'%\') OR products.type LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', specifications.type, \'%\')
WHERE lendings.user_id = ?
```

EDIT:

lendings table:

```
user_id       product_id
1             1
1             2
2             3
```

Specifications table:

```
productname   year        type     sn
name1         2012        1        1234
name2         2011        2        4321
name3         2010        3        3241
```

products table:

```
id            sn
1             AAAAAAAA1234
2             BBBBBBBB4321
3             CCCCCCCC3241
```

EDIT2:

```
SELECT products.id, 
       specifications.productname, 
       products.sn, 
       specifications.year, 
       lendings.lending_date
FROM products
INNER JOIN lendings ON products.id = lendings.product_id
INNER JOIN specifications ON products2.sn LIKE CONCAT(specifications.sn, \'%\') OR    products.type = specifications.type
WHERE lendings.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that means you don't have all the necesary join columns present in one of your joins and you are getting a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). In database terms, this means you are joining to a table and expected to join to a single row, but multiple rows match the criteria, so you are actually joining to more than one row. When this happens, you will get the same row multiple times (product row in your example) in your result.

It would have been better if you posted some test data so this scenario could be confirmed, but since you didn't, I would recommend checking each of your joins to make sure you are not getting multiple rows back for the given products row.

One part of your query I find particularly suspect is this join:

```
INNER JOIN specifications ON products.sn LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', specifications.sn, \'%\') OR products.type LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', specifications.type, \'%\')
```

You're joining using a `LIKE` operator, which seems to have a high chance of getting multiple rows.

Comment: It's because the specifications table only contain some of the Serial number.

Comment: But if it's joining to more than one specifications row, even though specifications only contains some of the serial numbers, it will mess up your results. If you can post your complete data example it would help a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to compare the only 4 numbers in specifications.sn and products.sn? Sometimes it's only the last 3 and maybe also typenumber. Depending on the product - It's a little bit tricky :(

Comment: If they are the last 4 characters, you could use substring function. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: It's different. Can I do a check in the query if it's 11 charters long it's 3 letters. if 12 it's 4 letters.

Comment: You could do something like this perhaps: where right(specification.sn,3) = products.sn or right(specification.sn,4) = products.sn.

Comment: No, you'd still use a join, I meant you would add this to your join clause instead of the concat stuff you were doing.

Comment: I think it works with the CONCAT() now, but the "productname" column returns the same name twice with the user_id = 1 / I have added my current query to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One of your Join on conditions is too slack then

for instance two lendings records pointing to the same product.